# Как отключить mouse события при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript

Пробую новую для себя библиотеку - swiper.js. Не совсем понимаю пока как она работает, поэтому и задаю этот вопрос.

Может кто знает, как отключить в swiper события мыши, и сделать прокрутку только с помощью touch событий?

HTML - код:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="./img/vaider.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="./img/retro.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="./img/town.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

JS - код:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',

    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```